# Http failure response for (url): 0 Unknown Error?

Tags: .net, angular

Estou com um código local. O front (Angular 8) envia uma requisição POST para o back (.net). Em outro computador funciona normalmente.

Porém no meu computador atual não funciona.

Retorna:

```
Http failure response for (url): 0 Unknown Error
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no console aparece:

```
POST (url) net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

se eu chamo a requisição direto do back retorna normal.
O que pode ser?
O CORS no back e front estão configurados.

Comment: já vi esse problema na versão 2.2 do .net core, no nosso caso resolvemos mudando a versão

Comment: Pensei nisso. Porém, em outro computador funciona normalmente. Só no "meu" que não. E em produção/ambiente de teste também funciona.

Comment: @LucasMiranda deu certo. O erro estava no 2.2.0 - mudei para o 2.2.204 e agora rodou. Atualizei o Runtime também. Obrigada. :)